# How to solve this Functional Equation (not sure if I named it right)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function-theorem

Basicaly, I had following equation to solve:
$$\phi'(t) = \frac{a}{b\cdot\cos(\phi(t)) + c}$$

After integrating it, I get the following one:
$$b\cdot\sin(\phi(t)) + c\cdot\phi(t) = a\cdot t$$
And that's where I spent hours. The only way for me is to try to guess the result, maybe I'm lack of some math techniques to solve it.

Will be glad for any advises and solutions.

Comment: You did forget the constant(s) of integration, which can be solved for with a boundary value problem.

Comment: @fibonatic I didn't forget it, it equeals to sero as phi(0) = 0 (and I implicitly used it). Didn't understand your last part about boundary value problem.

Comment: A boundary value problem consists of any moment in time, lets call it time $\tau$, at a which $\phi(\tau)=\phi_\tau$. If $\tau=0$ then it is called an initial value problem, like in your case. In general for higher order differential equations you will need more constraints, but those constraints can be placed at different moments in time for boundary value problems.

Answer (score 1):

This **is** the result. There is no way to get $\varphi(t)$ as a combination of elementary functions.

Comment: What is the reason of impossibility to get it as a combination of elementary functions? A theorem?

Comment: @AlexVelickiy You may take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: @thanasissdr according to this theorem, phi(t) "in principle (though not necessarily with an analytic expression) can exist" "at least in some disk". That doesn't help.